# Getting cell values into variables in DataGridView based on Grid coordinates

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Im working with a DataGridView with an imported CSV file where the values are delimited
with (,).. The grid works perfectly fine.

My *ultimate* goal is to hide the grid out of view from the user and access the data in the grid based on the coordinates of the grid specified i.e (The cell in column 5, row 6 contains the value "Taco") and I want to save that value to a variable...

Eventually I want to loop through all the values of a column and save them to individual variables to be later used. So far, this is what I have...

---

`

```
  Dim sReader As New StreamReader("book1.csv")

    Dim Record() As String

    For x As Integer = 0 To 17

        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(x, x)
    Next


    While sReader.Peek() <> -1
        Record = sReader.ReadLine().Split(",")
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Record)

    End While



    Dim cellval As String
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    cellval = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
    col = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X
    row = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y

    Label1.Text = cellval
    Label2.Text = col
    Label3.Text = row
```

`

---

Presently, that will only display the data in column 0, row 0 in those labels...

**Note:** 17 in the for loop is the amount of columns in the data i provided.. that number will never change.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: **DataGridView1[colindex][rowindex].FormattedValue** will give you value of the cell(co-ordinate), is that what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the value of a certain cell use the following:

DataGridView.rows([put the row number here]).cells([put the col number here]).value